# AWS Lambda send email without Verification

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I have (painfully) created a system where I have an API gateway passing the info from the HTML form to the LAMBDA function and an email is sent to me when someone contacts my webpage.
Now, the problem is, that I want to automatically send an email to thank them for contacting but I have hit a road block. I think it does not let me just do that, because such email address is not verified.

1. Is there a way, in the same LAMBDA function, to send an email back to the person without verifying the email?
2. Is there another way, by using the same Lambda function to do this? I want to stick to the same lambda function because is already working and I guess code can be added.
   Thanks

Here is the code

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
var ses = new AWS.SES()
var RECEIVER1 = 'admin email'
var RECEIVER11 = 'contact email'
var SENDER = 'sender email'

exports.handler = function (event, context) {console.log('Received event:', event) sendEmail(event, function (err, data) {context.done(err, null)})}

function sendEmail (event, done) {
var params = {

    Destination: {
    ToAddresses: [
        RECEIVER1
    ]
},
Message: {
    Body: {
        Text: {
            Data: 'Name: ' + event.name + '\nPhone: ' + event.phone + '\nEmail: ' + event.email + '\nDescription of email: ' + event.description,
            Charset: 'UTF-8'
        }
    },
    Subject: {
        Data: 'Variable: ' + event.name,
        Charset: 'UTF-8'
    }
},
Source: SENDER
}
ses.sendEmail(params, done)

var params1 = {

    Destination: {
    ToAddresses: [
        RECEIVER11
    ]
},
Message: {
    Body: {
        Text: {
            Data: ''

<html>              
...
</html>
,
Charset: 'UTF-8'
        }
    },
    Subject: {
        Data: 'Variable: ' + event.name,
        Charset: 'UTF-8'
    }
},
Source: SENDER
}
ses.sendEmail(params1, done)
}'
```

Comment: you can contact aws support to move your account out of sandbox.

Comment: I didnt know that... Thanks a lot...
Also, can you check the code and let me know if by creating a variable called CUSTOMER = event.email, and using that variable on a second piece of code identical to that one, if in theory the email will go back to the customer?
or should I make another Lambda function to do that? I would love to keep it on one function if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively, asking for an increased limit solved the issue.
Thanks to all that helped.